# How do I calculate the speedup properly?

Tags: parallel-computing, performance, program-optimization

I am trying to calculate the speedup of this, but I am getting the wrong answer:

> Assuming that we have a program where we have two execution phases. One phase takes 1 time unit to execute and can only execute sequentially. The other phase takes 3 times units to execute sequentially but can be perfectly parallelized. What is the maximum speedup you can achieve?

This is how I have tried to calculate it; I've used the parallelization formula, which states:

$1/((1-P)+P/n))$

Where:

```
S(n) is the theoretical speedup
P is the fraction of the algorithm that can be made parallel
n is the number of CPU threads
```

So using the formula in my case:

P is 75% as 3/4 is the total time

I assume n is 1 as nothing is mentioned about it

$1/((1-0,75)+0,75))=1$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you only use `1` thread, then of course you cannot expect any speedup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the phase can be perfectly parallelized then $n$ can be arbitrarily large.

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{(1-0.75)+0.75/n} = \frac{1}{0.25} = 4$

Comment: Why is n set to 0?

Comment: @GeorgeW it isn't, $1/n$ tends towards $0$ as $n$ tends towards infinity.